# Read from a file written in C with Java

Tags: java, c, file, binary

I have a binary file written in C and I want to read it in java. I wrote the file in C like this :

```
void Log(TCHAR *name,int age){
    write_int(file, 2012);
    write_int(file, 4);
    write_int(file, 16);
    write_int(file, 12);
    write_int(file, 58);
    write_int(file, 50);

    fwrite(&name, sizeof(name), 1, file);
    fwrite(&age, sizeof(age), 1, file);
    fflush(processusFile);
}
```

In Java I use the `BinaryFile` class http://www.heatonresearch.com/code/22/BinaryFile.java and I do this :

```
RandomAccessFile f = new RandomAccessFile("myfile.dat", "r");
BinaryFile binaryFile = new BinaryFile(f);
ArrayList<String> text = new ArrayList<>();
while (true) {
try {
    Calendar calendar = new GregorianCalendar();
    int year = (int) binaryFile.readDWord();
    int month = (int) binaryFile.readDWord();
    int date = (int) binaryFile.readDWord();
    int hourOfDay = (int) binaryFile.readDWord();
    int minute = (int) binaryFile.readDWord();
    int second = (int) binaryFile.readDWord();

    calendar.set(year, month, date, hourOfDay, minute, second); 
    System.out.println(binaryFile.readFixedString(64));    
    catch (Exception e) {
        break;  
    }
}
```

This is not working for char* but for int it works. How I can write Strings?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because `sizeof(name)` is the size of a `char` pointer on your system, *not* the length of the string. You need to write out the length separately from the string, too.

```
size_t len = strlen(name);
write_int(file, len);
fwrite(&name, len, sizeof(char), file);
```

Comment: i did this in c code and call my function with params("TestName",44) but in java when i do this : `System.out.println(">"+length+">" + binaryFile.readFixedString(length));` i have this in out : >8>?A@

Comment: @khelch I assume that you read the length before reading the string, right?

Comment: yes i have this instruction `int length = (int) binaryFile.readDWord();` before System.out

Comment: @khelch This is almost certainly because Java string is composed of 16-bit characters, while C string uses 8-bit characters. Try reading `length` bytes from your binary file, and then use `String` constructor that takes an array of bytes.

Answer (score 1):

This is wrong:

```
fwrite(&name, sizeof(name), 1, file);
```

this will only write a number of characters that correspond to the size of the **pointer**, typically 4.

If the size you want to write out is fixed (looks like the Java code expects 64 characters), you need to pass that size somehow to `Log()`.

There is no way in C to figure out the size of the array that (might have been) was passed as the first argument to `Log()` from within the function, which is why you must make it explicit.

Answer (score 1):

You must take care type "int".

int in java is always 32bit, not so in C. In C it may be 16,32,64 bit

Answer (score 1):

Your `fwrite` statement doesn't look right:

```
fwrite(&name, sizeof(name), 1, file);
```

You actually want something like:

```
fwrite(name, sizeof(TCHAR), strlen(name) + 1, file);
```

Comment: If you're going that route, use `sizeof(*name)` in favor of `sizeof(TCHAR)` - its clearer and will continue to work if the type of `name` changes.